# JavaScript , Inquirer : Getting an error for user defined Imported function

Tags: javascript-objects, inquirer

The below program is taking the CLI input from the user and is printing to the text file.

**Question **: the program is giving an error when passing the user promise "result" to the imported user defined function "writeFile" as  "writeFile" is not a function . But it's working fine if the exported function is written as module.exports={writeFile} instead of this module.exports=writeFile in page-write.js file .Please advise why it is happening like this .

```
app.js file

const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const {
    writeFile
} = require('./utils/page-write');

const userInput = () => {
    return inquirer.prompt([{
        type: 'input',
        name: 'userName',
        message: 'What is your name?',
        validate: (name) => {
            if (name) return true;
            else {
                console.log("Input your name");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }, {
        type: 'rawlist',
        name: 'communication',
        message: 'What is your preferred method of communication?',
        choices: ['homephone', 'email', 'mobile'],
        default: 1
    }])
}

userInput().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    return writeFile(JSON.stringify(result));
}).then(writeFileResponse => {
    console.log(writeFileResponse)
}).catch((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

---------------------------------------------
page - write.js file

const fs = require('fs');

const writeFile = (userData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return fs.writeFile('./index.txt', userData, err => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return
            }
            resolve({
                ok: true,
                message: "data is sucessfully written"
            })
        })
    })
}

module.exports = writeFile;
```